# Save results in Promise after it's done

Tags: javascript, promise

I use Promise to do a http post. I can see results been output inside `then()`.
How can I access `data` later? Tried `resultPromise.then()`, did not produce same result.

```
let resultPromise = 
fetch(cleanUrl, {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
//what I intent to do
if(data.isSafe == ture) {
   //do something
}
else {
    //do somehing
}
```

**Update 1**

Added description of what I want to do with data.

**Update 2**
Move the code inside `then()` as @Nicholas Tower suggested.

Comment: The `resultPromise` will hold the result of the `data => { console.log('Success:', data); }` callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
```

Since there's no return value here, the promise it creates resolves to `undefined`. Either delete this `.then` (in which case the previous `.then` will determine the value), or have it re-return the data.

```
.then(data => {
   console.log('Success:', data);
   return data;
})
```

The `.catch` block may require similar treatment. Any errors are currently being swallowed and replaced with resolving to `undefined`. If you want to re-throw the error, do one of the following:

```
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
  throw error;
});

// or
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: …and same for the `.catch(…)` callback that returns `undefined`.

Comment: Good suggestion. Added a note about the .catch

Comment: Does the return make resultPromise = data?

Comment: `resultPromise` will be a promise, that eventually resolves to the data. It will not be the data itself. You will use the promise like you showed in your question: `resultPromise.then(data => { console.log('Success2:', data); });`

Comment: How can I get data outside `then()`?

Comment: I got `undefined` when do ```resultPromise.then(data => {
   console.log('Success:', data);
   return data;
})``` later

Comment: `How can I get data outside then()`  Short version: you can't. `.then` and `async/await` are the only ways to get notified when the data is ready. So either call `.then` on the promise and put your code inside the `.then` callback, or put your code in an `async` function and `await` the promise. `I got undefined when i do /*..*/` ok, i'll need more details about what you changed in order to debug it. Perhaps you can update your question with your changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239763/discussion-between-daolin-and-nicholas-tower).